# A method should be in the class which realises a action or in the realised class?

Tags: java, oop

Maybe the title is a little confusing, but I didn't know how to say it properly (my English is not good at all, so sorry if it is harder to understand).

Let's say we got 2 classes, Person and Group, and a person can join a group. Both got a Collection of the joined groups or the persons that already joined the group.

I want a method to allow me to do that. Would it better to have a method in the Person class which is joinGroup(Group g) or a method in the Group which is addPerson(Person p)? In any way the method have to do some checks and not only add the objects to the Collections.

I'm using Java but I think it's not important as it's more a design questions.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Not all person should join a group. That is, it is possible that a person may not be part of any group. 
But a Group should have person.

So i think, Group Should have the method adddPerson(Person)

Comment: Aah, I understand, sound like a good reason to put it in the Group class.

Answer (score 1):

Maybe you can do somehing like this.

```
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.Iterator;

public class Main {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        Person person = new Person("Seko", "35");
        Group group = new Group("Family");
        group.addPersonToGroup(person);

        System.out.println("Groups belonging_to Seko person");
        person.printGroupList();
        System.out.println("Persons belonging_to family group");
        group.printPersonList();
    }

    static class Person {
        String name;
        String age;
        ArrayList<Group> groups = new ArrayList<>();
        public Person(String name, String age) {
           this.name = name;
           this.age = age;
        }
        private void joinToGroup(Group g) {
            groups.add(g);
        }

        private void printGroupList(){
            System.out.println(groups);
        }

        @Override
        public String toString() {
            return "Person{" +
                    "name='" + name + '\'' +
                    ", age='" + age + '\'' +
                    '}';
        }
    }

    static class Group {
        String groupName;
        ArrayList<Person> persons = new ArrayList<>();

        public Group(String groupName){
            this.groupName = groupName;
        }

        private void addPersonToGroup(Person p){
            persons.add(p);
            p.joinToGroup(this);
        }

        private void printPersonList(){
            Iterator<Person> iterate = persons.iterator();
            while(iterate.hasNext()){
                System.out.println(iterate.next());
            }

        }
        @Override
        public String toString() {
            return "Group{" +
                    "groupName='" + groupName + '\'' +
                    '}';
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: But doing this to add someone to a group I have to call both methods, so I think it could be better to have a method that adds the group to the person and the person to the group.

Comment: Ok i got you. I edited the code and add --p.joinToGroup(this);-- addPersonToGroup method in Group class.  Now you can call both methods just calling addPersonToGroup.

Comment: Yes, that was what I was asking, I need also to do some checks before the person is added to the group so it looks like putting the method in the Group class would be better.